# Hibernate Join Tables

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have two tables:

Person

```
ID | NAME | EMAIL_ID (foreign key of Email.ID)
```

Email

```
ID | EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

I need to pull back the data into the following Entity but I am unsure how to join `PERSON.EMAIL_ID` with `EMAIL.ID` using annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class PersonEntity {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    // How do I do a one to one join here?
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

How can I use annotations properly so that the `emailAddress` field maps to the `EMAIL.EMAIL_ADDRESS` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Person` entity should join with the `Email` entity and not the emailAddress property directly.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class PersonEntity {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Email email;
}
```

But it is strange to have an entity only for emails. Do you only ensure email is unique ? In this case Person entity can have an emailAddress with `@Column(unique = true)`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class PersonEntity {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

Comment: I agree it is strange, we created the join table to future-proof it in case we need multiple emails

Comment: In this case you should prefer the @OneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't do joins in Hibernate. Rather use mapping and HQL. 
A good example can be found here : 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/